# phpunit run function on failing test

Tags: phpunit

When a test fails, I want to run a function (that searches for a certain string in a database and then greps for that string in a bunch of files) and output the results - is that possible?

For context, the test searches for two columns in a database.  When it fails, I want to know if the string appears in one of the columns, and I also want to search a file for the string as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in an [extension](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/extending-phpunit.html#extending-the-testrunner). The `AfterTestFailureHook` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::onNotSuccessfulTest(Throwable $t)`. This method is called after a test has failed. Do not forget to call `parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($t)`, though.